How to git clone private repo with private submodules with https url?
I have a private github repo which contains multiple private submodules (all using https url).
Some GUI git clients like GitKraken can clone the repo recursively for me. I can also use git command on Mac to clone https url recursively. I believe it's using the macos keychain. https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain
How to do the same on Linux. I don't want to embed the PAT in https url, and I can't update the submodule https urls. I also don't want to change everything to use ssh keys as that will break some CI.

Use GitHub CLI who provides a credential manager.
Read

https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/caching-your-github-credentials-in-git?platform=linux
Main website https://cli.github.com/
Linux installation: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md

